# React/Meteor VS React/Flux for website, mobile app and canvas game

Tags: javascript, canvas, mobile, meteor, flux

I'm building a real time game using [HTML Canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) and [socket.io](http://socket.io/) on [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/) web server (and [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) for all part of the website except the core game on canvas).
This game will be accessible from Desktop browser and Mobile apps (at least Android and iOS)

I'm looking the new tends and I'm really interested to migrate to something like [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app) or [Flux](https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs).

Both handle React UI and socket functionality:

- Meteor: [Publish/Subscribe](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe)
- Flux: [Dispatcher/Register](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/dispatcher.html) (I don't know if I have really understand this part, it's the same thing but a different way, right?)

**React, Canvas**

I have to deal with both of them, actually the canvas is rendered by React, and a callback is called when something new have to be displayed and a pure JavaScript function draw the canvas.
I saw some lib (like [react-canvas](https://github.com/Flipboard/react-canvas)) but i don't know if react can handle a 30FPS game rendering ? And Mobile ?

**Mobile apps**

I know Meteor handle Mobile apps, but React seems to also have [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/). But it seems to create different apps, and not to import the original one (even if the core game is on web canvas, so only the rest have to be done)

**React+Flux = <3**

I really like React and Meteor just handle it while Flux is a part of the same project. 
Moreover, Flux seems to be really more scalable, but complex.

What's the choices to do ? What's tips to know ?

Comment: react can handle updating lots of dom elements for a game (4,000 elms at ~32 fps on a thinkpad). http://danml.com/intrahtml/demos/perf/ shows that it's faster than naive dom updates, but not as fast as a custom routine would be.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based. In one corner wearing the red trunks and weighing in at 152 lbs we have Meteor. In the other corner in the blue trunks we have Flux...